# Sum of Small number in the given range ignoring Character in Array, Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to sum the small number in an array which has both number and letters.

Row values are like: 1,NA,B,0,-1,NA,-1.

In this range i am trying to sum least 5 numerical values, since there is only 4 numerical values
i am getting error. please let me know how this can be done to ignore alphabets.

here is the formula i am using

```
{=SUM(SMALL(A1:G1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))))}
```

also i tried

```
{=SUM(SMALL((ISNUMBER(A1:G1)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:5"))))}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use COUNT with MIN to set the last:

```
=SUM(SMALL(A1:G1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,MIN(COUNT(A1:G1),5)))
```

Depending on ones version the may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

I changed the INDIRECT to  INDEX to remove the volatility of the function.

If you do not care about the volatility just replace `"1:5"` with `"1:" & MIN(COUNT(A1:G1),5)` in your formula.  But I would not recommend it, as volatile function will calculate every time there is a change in Excel causing unneeded calculations.

Comment: Thank you. this worked for all cases when changed $ZZ1 to $ZZ$1